# What is the distribution of the $k^{th}$ highest value of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution, order-statistics

Let X be an N-dimensional multivariate normal, $X \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\mu$ is Nx1 and $\Sigma$ is NxN. If we take a draw of $X$ from this distribution and then sort $X$ from largest to smallest, what is the distribution of the $k^\text{th}$ entry?

Comment: If $X=Z \sim \mbox{N}_N(\boldsymbol{0}_N, \boldsymbol{I}_N)$, could you answer the question?  Then you need only do a location-scale transformation to get your desired result.

Comment: There is no closed form formula in the general case (and it does not follow from the standard Normal case).